# Java Stream - Retrieving repeated records from CSV

Tags: java, csv, stream

I searched the site and didn't find something similar. I'm newbie to using the Java stream, but I understand that it's a replacement for a loop command. However, I would like to know if there is a way to filter a CSV file using stream, as shown below, where only the repeated records are included in the result and grouped by the Center field.

**Initial CSV file**

[image]

**Final result**

[image]

In addition, the same pair cannot appear in the final result inversely, as shown in the table below:

**This shouldn't happen**

[image]

Is there a way to do it using stream and grouping at the same time, since theoretically, two loops would be needed to perform the task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you meant different record except the id field right ? because it make it all the record different in your example.

Comment: Are those real names and birthdates?

Comment: Closely related question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47226834/2513200

Comment: This one is for numbers, but the ideas apply here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31341963/2513200

Comment: @Bohemian No. The data are fake !!! LOL.

Comment: @RobertReynolds The CSV file is from a database. The users inputs repeat data, so the primary key is different indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your examples is you consider an entry as duplicate if all the attributes have same value except the `ID`. You can use `anymatch` for this:

```
list.stream().filter(x ->
                list.stream().anyMatch(y -> isDuplicate(x, y))).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

**So what does the isDuplicate(x,y) do?**

This returns a `boolean`. You can check whether all the entries have same value except the id in this method:

```
private boolean isDuplicate(CsvEntry x, CsvEntry y) {
    return !x.getId().equals(y.getId())
            && x.getName().equals(y.getName())
            && x.getMother().equals(y.getMother())
            && x.getBirth().equals(y.getBirth());
}
```

I've assumed you've taken all the entries as `String`. Change the checks according to the type. This will give you the duplicate entries with their corresponding `ID`

Comment: This is not an efficient solution.

Comment: Thought of using hashset, but that will not give what OP have asked

Comment: It can, with the right element type (with appropriate `equals` method). Or a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) with a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: @devReddit Hi... Thank you so much for your reply. You're right: hashset doesn't solve my problem. Btw, to be able to group the result is it necessary to take the resulting stream above and apply a group to the selection, right ? Can't group in the same command ?

Comment: @AdalbertoJoséBrasaca You can use `Collectors.groupingBy(Function<? super  T,?  extends K>  classifier)` to group the results based on specific property in the `collect()` of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one pass as a stream with O(n) efficiency:

```
class PersonKey {
    // have a field for every column that is used to detect duplicates
    String center, name, mother, birthdate;
    public PersonKey(String line) {
        // implement String constructor
    }
    // implement equals and hashCode using all fields
}

List<String> lines; // the input 
Set<PersonKey> seen = new HashSet<>();
List<String> unique = lines.stream()
  .filter(p -> !seen.add(new PersonKey(p))
  .distinct()
  .collect(toList());
```

The trick here is that a HashSet has constant time operations and its add() method returns false if the value being added is already in the set, true otherwise.

Comment: +1 although personally, if I have to use 2 stateful filters in a stream, I'd prefer the loop. If I'm not mistaken, the `found`-Set could be dropped if we can live with e.g. a `LinkedHashSet`-result instead of a list.

Comment: @hulk you are mistaken :) the problem is the objects being collected in the set are not the objects needed in the result. You could avoid the 2nd set by by using distinct after mapping to an object whose equals method ignored its `id` field, which is a violation of all things good. But internally distinct uses a HashSet anyway, so this code is no heavier - you’re just seeing the set. A LinkedHashSet is not needed - either way always finds the first unique item.

Comment: Ah I see, I missed that indeed. Well then, this is probably as good as it gets :)

Comment: You can probably use a csv driver to run that as a sql query

Comment: @Bohemian I don't think I expressed myself correctly. What I need to know is a list of which records are duplicates, not just whether they are. So I think using hashset doesn't solve the problem. Btw, thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: @AdalbertoJoséBrasaca have you tried this code? It creates a list of duplicate entries (named `unique`). And it does so in linear time complexity, whereas the currently accepted answer has O(N^2) time complexity.

Comment: @Hulk the OP asked for each of the duplicate entries, for example, if you have [1,1,2,3,4,3,3,5] then OP asked for [1,1,3,3,3] as output, he'll later apply group in them, that's what he asked for in the comment of my answer. Implementation of hashset in that way doesn't provide what OP asked for.

Comment: @AdalbertoJoséBrasaca Sorry - I misread your question. No problem, even easier: see edited answer.